# Pod crash while HPA statefulsets scale down

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-statefulset, horizontalpodautoscaler

While performing a scale-down event from HPA(for a statefulset) if one of the terminating pod(s) crashes abruptly before the graceful termination; whether the pod restarts/reschedules and then tries to gracefully terminate/scale-down once again. The behavior is important to know as there is a preStop hook implementation(data recovery for terminating pod) while terminating and this might never get called when a abrupt termination happens while HPA scale-down.

Regards,
Balu

Comment: I agree with @Abhishek, I have found older tutorial about [Graceful scaledown of stateful apps in Kubernetes](https://medium.com/@marko.luksa/graceful-scaledown-of-stateful-apps-in-kubernetes-2205fc556ba9) and they have used [statefulset scaledown controller](https://github.com/luksa/statefulset-scaledown-controller) here, maybe that´s what you should consider to use instead of doing data recovery in preStop hook?

Comment: @jt97, Thanks. I had already seen the above writeup from Marko; a good solution indeed but the author himself has claimed this as a PoC and the same I believe is still not part of the official K8s feature stack.

Comment: yes, this is still not part of the k8s feature. Maybe in the future.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is, if graceful termination fails, the pods are not restarts/rescheduled.

Pods may fail due to any reason (node issue, pod evicted etc.) in such scenario preStop hook is never invoked.

And this is by design, even if one writes a logic to restart/reschedule the pod will not help to restore the data from the pod (as it will be fresh pod).

Comment: Thanks Abhishek. Understood that pods fail/crash/terminate due to many reasons but in those cases the reschedule happens after a time-period to maintain the replicas and this takes care of the statefulset pod recovery as the identity is maintained across restarts/reschedules. The only difference of pod fail/crash/terminate during HPA scale down event is that the same statefulset pods won't get started/scheduled until the next scale up event. Anyways I am concluding on the above statement that pod crash during a HPA scale down event won't restart/reschedule the same.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, I meant Pod failure during scale down not in a normal scenario.